# Client testing - Runtime trait implementation approach

Tags: testing, client

When writing tests for client module I'm having troubles instantiating gadget for the client with the error:

> the trait `module_primitives::ModuleApi<sp_runtime::generic::Block<sp_runtime::generic::Header<u64, BlakeTwo256>, sc_network_test::Extrinsic>>` is not implemented for
> `RuntimeApiImpl<sp_runtime::generic::Block<sp_runtime::generic::Header<u64, BlakeTwo256>, sc_network_test::Extrinsic>, substrate_test_runtime_client::client::Client<substrate_test_runtime_client::sc_client_db::Backend<sp_runtime::generic::Block<sp_runtime::generic::Header<u64, BlakeTwo256>, sc_network_test::Extrinsic>>, LocalCallExecutor<sp_runtime::generic::Block<sp_runtime::generic::Header<u64, BlakeTwo256>, sc_network_test::Extrinsic>, substrate_test_runtime_client::sc_client_db::Backend<sp_runtime::generic::Block<sp_runtime::generic::Header<u64, BlakeTwo256>, sc_network_test::Extrinsic>>, NativeElseWasmExecutor<LocalExecutorDispatch>>, sp_runtime::generic::Block<sp_runtime::generic::Header<u64, BlakeTwo256>, sc_network_test::Extrinsic>, substrate_test_runtime_client::substrate_test_runtime::RuntimeApi>>`

Implementation:

```
pub(crate) type ModuleTestParams = ModuleParams<PeersFullClient, Backend>;
pub(crate) type PeerData = Option<ModuleTestParams>;

pub(crate) type ModulePeer = Peer<PeerData, PeersClient>;

pub(crate) struct ModuleTestNet {
    peers: Vec<ModulePeer>,
}

impl ModuleTestNet {
    pub(crate) fn new(n_authority: usize, n_full: usize) -> Self {
        let mut net = ModuleTestNet { peers: Vec::with_capacity(n_authority + n_full) };
        for _ in 0..n_authority {
            net.add_authority_peer();
        }
        for _ in 0..n_full {
            net.add_full_peer();
        }
        net
    }

    pub(crate) fn add_authority_peer(&mut self) {
        self.add_full_peer_with_config(FullPeerConfig {
            notifications_protocols: vec!["module/1".into()],
            is_authority: true,
            ..Default::default()
        })
    }

    pub(crate) fn add_full_peer(&mut self) {
        todo!()
    }
    pub(crate) fn generate_blocks(
        &mut self,
        count: usize,
        session_length: u64,
        validator_set: &ValidatorSet<AuthorityId>,
    ) {
        self.peer(0).generate_blocks(count, BlockOrigin::File, |builder| {
            let mut block = builder.build().unwrap().block;

            if *block.header.number() % session_length == 0 {
                add_auth_change_digest(&mut block.header, validator_set.clone());
            }

            block
        });
    }
}
```

TestNetFactory is implemented.

Then trait:

```
pub(crate) struct RuntimeApi {
    inner: TestApi,
}

impl ProvideRuntimeApi<Block> for TestApi {
    type Api = RuntimeApi;
    fn runtime_api<'a>(&'a self) -> ApiRef<'a, Self::Api> {
        RuntimeApi { inner: self.clone() }.into()
    }
}

sp_api::mock_impl_runtime_apis! {
    impl ModuleApi<Block> for RuntimeApi {}
}
```

And instantiation (where error comes from):

```
fn initialize_module(
    net: &mut ModuleTestNet,
    peers: Vec<(usize, &ModuleKeyring, ModuleTestParams)>,
) -> impl Future<Output = ()> {
    let voters = FuturesUnordered::new();

    for (peer_id, key, module_params) in peers.into_iter() {
        let gadget = start_module_gadget::<_, _, _>(module_params);

        fn assert_send<T: Send>(_: &T) {}
        assert_send(&gadget);
        voters.push(gadget);
    }

    voters.for_each(|_| async move {})
}
```

Declaration of gadget starting function:

```
pub async fn start_module_gadget<B, BE, C>(module_params: ModuleParams<C, BE>)
where
    B: Block,
    BE: Backend<B>,
    C: Client<B, BE>,
    C::Api: ModuleApi<B>,
{
    let ModuleParams { client, backend, key_store, rpc_send } = module_params;

    let worker_params = worker::WorkerParams { client, backend, key_store, rpc_send };

    let mut worker = worker::ModuleWorker::<_, _, _>::new(worker_params);

    worker.run().await
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing a bound `C: ProvideRuntimeApi<B>` on your `start_module_gadget` function.

Comment: added but getting same error...

Comment: was able to fix this by extending `ModuleWorker` and `ModuleParams` with `R: ProvideRuntimeApi<B>` and moving `R:Api` there. weird stuff but marking as correct answer.